# Asterisk abandoned calls

Tags: asterisk, cdr

I have some realtime tables, those named cdr and queue_log. I can get reports from that tables. These are "Cdr details" and "Abandoned calls". But i have a problem. I can see who abandoned the queue and do voicemail.

But what about other stuffs. If somebody close call before reaching queue or voicemail message. How can I detect them? That's important, because some customers doesn't want to create voicemail message. I don't want to lose them.

Answer (score 0):

There are NO WAY say who abandoned queue.

Reason is simple: let say you have queue with 100 agents and nobody answered. Who abandoned?

You have 2 options

1) on incoming call save cid to some table, compare with queue_log in 10 minutes.

2) check cdr and see if you have calls that have be reported. optionally mark such calls by CDR(userfield).